# get 401 Unauthorized erro when using rapid api and here are the screenshot of api doc

Tags: angular, api, http-status-code-401, rapidapi

[image]

and this is my code to call api :

apiBaseURL= `${environment.baseUrl}`

constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

getTeams() {

```
let authToken = {
  "x-rapidapi-key": "ba0a665d73msh8c54a216ac1d6c5p1f80c4jsn312950ace3e0",
  "x-rapidapi-host": "api-football-v1.p.rapidapi.com"
}
const reqHeader = new HttpHeaders({
  'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  'Authorization': `Bearer ${authToken}`
})

return this.http.get('https://api-football- 
v1.p.rapidapi.com/v2/teams/team/33', {headers: reqHeader })
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to subscribe to API on RapidAPI Hub before using it. This can be the possible reason why you're getting 401 unauthorized response.

If the error still persists after a successful subscription, try adding `x-rapidapi-key` and `x-rapidapi-host` as the custom headers.

Answer (score 0):

Either you haven't subscribed the API,
or
The key is wrong
or
The basic plan got expired which gives you 500 requests a month.

check all the above, in case you are doing a learning activity I advice you to signup from a new acc and re subscribe the FREE basic plan (don't forget to change the API key though)

if you are an enterprise, kindly update the plan as free is good enough only till development purposes.